# Can you set up a Telegram group with more than one owner?

Tags: telegram

Is there a way to have shared ownership of a Telegram group? If not, what can you do if the owner of a group suddenly becomes inactive or let say I want to make a group with shared ownership in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have more than 1 owner in Telegram groups as of now. However, you can  add administrators with same roles as an owner.

> Note: You can also transfer ownership between administrators but only
> by owner

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Telegram avoids enabling "automatic ownership transfer" after deletion or suspension of owner's account for scamming reasons where admins take over a group by reporting a scam conversation with owner and then blackmail owner after his account has been deleted. However, this threat is not of any value if the problem concerns Topics.

Comment: If part of the solution is only linked please add it here. I removed the "please create traffic on my web content" part. If you provide the solution here and useful but not essential info is there, you can link, but please rephrase it. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion

Comment: firstly if you have noticed my points (<50) you know I can't comment unless it is directly to my post. secondly, I did not make a bug thread for my own benefits and this exactly what ownership transfer is needed for. Anyway, I explain it again here, Please see https://bugs.telegram.org/c/27512 thread and like my suggestion so that old groups without owners also can enable their topics when Telegram notice this problem. Thanks.